# Is there a way to access system keyboard layout file using android.R.layout.?

Tags: android, keyboard, multilingual, android-input-method

I am working on an app where the user would like the flexibility of choosing either French, Greek or English as input for one EditText field.

I understand we cannot change the input language of our keyboard simply in the code as we need WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS which is only available to system apps.

I have followed the guide [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615) to create a custom keyboard.

Is there a way to access the system keyboard layout using `android.R.layout.??` instead of creating a custom layout?

Comment: Related: [Using unicode for a custom android keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48876029/295004)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create custom keyboard with Russian Alphabet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870025/how-to-create-custom-keyboard-with-russian-alphabet)

Comment: @MorrisonChang - Thank you, I have updated the question as I got the Unicode answer from the links you shared. Do you have any suggestions on accessing the system keyboard layout?

Comment: The system keyboard could be a custom keyboard app, so as you don't want other apps interfering with your app's operation, you shouldn't be able to interfere with theirs. So no you can't access it, additionally any keyboard action could be from a hardware device rather than a software keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can use unicode of Greek/French symbols as labels (sorry about legibility below of all of them)

XML file for Greek like this

```
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="0391" android:keyLabel="α" />
        <Key android:codes="0392" android:keyLabel="β"/>
        <Key android:codes="0394" android:keyLabel="δ"/>
    </Row>
```

Here are the greek letters below:

> Greek letter Lower case Unicode Upper case Unicode alpha α 03b1 A 0391
>   beta β 03b2 B 0392 gamma γ 03b3 Γ 0393 delta δ 03b4 Δ 0394 epsilon ϵ
>   03b5 E 0395 zeta ζ 03b6 Z 0396 eta η 03b7 H 0397 theta θ 03b8 Θ 0398
>   iota ι 03b9 I 0399 kappa κ 03ba K 039a lambda λ 03bb Λ 039b mu μ 03bc
>   M 039c nu ν 03bd N 039d xi ξ 03be Ξ 039e omicron o 03bf O 039f pi π
>   03c0 Π 03a0 rho ρ 03c1 P 03a1 sigma σ 03c3 Σ 03a3 tau τ 03c4 T 03a4
>   upsilon υ 03c5 ϒ 03a5 phi ϕ 03c6 Φ 03a6 chi χ 03c7 X 03a7 psi ψ 03c8 Ψ
>   03a8 omega ω 03c9 Ω 03a9

Here are the french letters:

> Glyph Common name Windows Reference   Unicode Vowels with diacritic
>   marks à a with grave    Alt0224 à    00E0 À  capital a with
>   grave   Alt0192 À    00C0 â  a with circumflex   Alt0226 â 00E2
>   Â   capital A with circumflex   Alt0194 Â 00C2 è  e with
>   grave   Alt0232 è    00E8 È  capital e with
>   grave   Alt0200 È    00C8 é  e with acute    Alt0233 é    00E9
>   É   capital e with acute    Alt0201 É    00C9 ê  e with
>   circumflex  Alt0234 ê 00EA Ê  capital E with
>   circumflex  Alt0202 Ê 00CA ë  e with dieresis Alt0235 ë  00EB
>   Ë   capital E with dieresis Alt0203 Ë  00CB î  i with
>   circumflex  Alt0238 î 00EE Î  capital I with
>   circumflex  Alt0206 Î 00CE ï  i with dieresis Alt0239 ï  00EF
>   Ï   capital I with dieresis Alt0207 Ï  00CF ô  o with
>   circumflex  Alt0244 ô 00F4 Ô  capital O with
>   circumflex  Alt0212 Ô 00D4 ù  u with grave    Alt0249 ù    00F9
>   Ù   capital U with grave    Alt0217 Ù    00D9 û  u with
>   circumflex  Alt0251 û 00FB Û  capital U with
>   circumflex  Alt0219 Û 00DB ü  u with dieresis Alt0252 ü  00FC
>   Ü   capital U with dieresis Alt0220 Ü  00DC ÿ  y with
>   dieresis    Alt0255 ÿ  00FF Ÿ  capital Y with
>   dieresis    Alt0159 Ÿ  0178 Other letters ç    c with
>   cedilla Alt0231 ç    00E7 Ç  capital C with
>   cedilla Alt0199 Ç    00C7 œ  oe ligature Alt0156 œ 0153
>   Œ   capital OE ligature Alt0140 Œ 0152 Punctuation «  left
>   guillemet   Alt0171 « 00AB »  right guillemet Alt0187 » 00AB
>   ‹   left single guillemet   Alt0139 ‹    2039 ›  right single
>   guillemet   Alt0155 ›    203A “  left double
>   quote   Alt0147 “ 201C ”  right double quote  Alt0148 ” 201D
>   ‘   left single quote   Alt0145 ‘ 2018
>   ’   apostrophe  Alt0146 ’ 2019 —  em dash
>   (cadratin)  Alt0151 — 2014 –  en dash
>   (demi-cadratin) Alt0150 – 2013 Other characters € euro
>   sign    Alt0128 €  20AC    no-break space  Alt0160    00A0

Here is the link for Unicode in wikipedia with all of them:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Comment: thank you for sharing the Unicode. I have updated the question as it turned out to be a duplicate. Any pointers for using system keyboard layout instead of custom layout?